# Bootstrap 4 Navbar overlaps container while navigating

Tags: html, css

I'm facing a issue with my Bootstrap 4 template.

The navbar overlaps a part of the container which I'm navigating to (using href="#containername"). I'm using a fixed navbar, and I have put the body padding-top in the stylesheet.

The website looks like:
[The start point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbKcQ.png)
But when you click any menu item, the button roadmap for instance, then you'll get:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lZYn.png)
As you can see, the navbar overlaps the roadmap container with a few pixels. Why?

The navbar code:

```
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light fixed-top navbar-gd bg-white">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="assets/images/logo.png" width="45" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse"
    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
```

And I have add the padding as:

```
body {
    padding-top: 5rem;
}
```

The navbar-gd class contains:

```
    .navbar-gd {
        height: 80px;
        max-height: 80px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 25px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 25px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
        b

ox-shadow: 0 0 25px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

The containers with the container-space class contains the following code:

```
.container-space {
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.content-container {
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 40px 0px 40px 0px;
}
```

The roadmap part:

```
<div class="container-fluid background-blauw" id="roadmap">
  <div class="content-container">
      <h1 class="header subtext text-center text-white">Onze roadmap voor dit jaar</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="timeline">
        <li>
          <div class="timeline-badge success">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="timeline-panel">
            <div class="timeline-heading">
              <h5 class="timeline-title">Initiatie project</h5>
              <p>
                <small class="text-muted">
                  <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                  uitgevoerd op 1 Januari 2018
                  </small>
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-body">
              <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="timeline-inverted">
            <div class="timeline-badge warning">
              <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-panel">
              <div class="timeline-heading">
                <h5 class="timeline-title">Beta fase 1</h5>
                <p>
                  <small class="text-muted">
                    <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                    staat gepland op 1 September</small>
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="timeline-body">
                <p>In deze fase gaan we het platform met test transacties testen, deze transacties worden binnen het testnet uitgevoerd.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
              <div class="timeline-badge warning">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="timeline-panel">
                <div class="timeline-heading">
                  <h5 class="timeline-title">Beta fase 2</h5>
                  <p>
                    <small class="text-muted">
                      <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> staat gepland op 1 November</small>
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-body">
                  <p>In deze fase gaan we het platform met echte transacties testen, deze transacties worden binnen het mainnet uitgevoerd.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="timeline-inverted">
                <div class="timeline-badge warning">
                  <i class="fa fa-rocket"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-panel">
                  <div class="timeline-heading">
                    <h5 class="timeline-title">Lancering platform</h5>
                    <p>
                      <small class="text-muted">
                        <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> staat gepland op 1 December</small>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="timeline-body">
                    <p>Met de lancering van het platform maken we het voor iedereen mogelijk om snel en veilig Guldens te kopen. De lancering van het platform willen we dan ook groots aanpakken. Alle beta testers zijn welkom op het lanceringsevent!</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you please share your code? I think you have missed something :)

Comment: Hi Matt, I have add the code

Comment: Unfortunately with your code I can not replicate your issue, however just after a quick look: if your ".navbar-gd"  has got an "height: 80px;" I think your "content-container" should have a padding-top of at least "90px"

Comment: p.s. I think that the the "navbar" code in your example is incomplete...

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't adjusting the margin on your top container suffice?

```
.yourTopContainer {
    margin-top: 50px; /* insert your navBar height */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the .content-container code into:

```
.content-container {
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 100px 0px 100px 0px;
}
```

And added the content-container class to every container, the result is way better now but it still overlaps the container.

Comment: could be possible to create a Snippet? :)